# Force users to always log in and show no content

Tags: 7, users

I am using Drupal 7.31 and I installed the MD Alpine theme. I have a site which loads a video on the front page. I want to hide this front page. When users come to my site, I want them to be redirected to the login form.

I tried changing the home page to /user and that was a huge mistake. I did manage to undo this. I also went into the permissions and removed any permission for the anonymous user, including the permission to view published content.

I know I have seen this question before, and it seems like there might be a module that can fix that. I am willing to make some configuration change.

Answer (score 1):

On the Structure > Blocks page, configure the Main Content block.  Within the Roles section, check Authenticated User.

Move the User Login block in the Content region.  This allows the Login screen to appear even if they are not logged in.

If you want to redirect them to the login page, you can install the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and create a rule that whenever an anonymous user loads a page, and the page path is not user*, then redirect them to /user.